# WPF - Binding SolidColorBrush inside DataGrid not working

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid

Hi and thank you for stopping by.

I need to bind a SolidColorBrush to a DataGrid Cell on runtime - the ViewModel for the DataGrid contains a property of type SolidColorBrush and the column itself is filled by a DataGridTemplateColumn:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="source column" Width="3.5*">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border Background="{Binding Path=SourceColumnBackground}">
                <Label x:Name="txbSourceName" Content="{Binding Path=SourceColumnDescriptionString}"></Label>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.SourceColumns, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" 
                        DisplayMemberPath="ColumnDescription"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

(Using a border has been a test as I had similar problems binding a background to a ComboBox (Windows 8.1)).

Binding of the text works as a charm, binding of the ItemsSource for the ComboBox works as well. The only thing not working is the Background.

I tested it outside of the DataGrid (in the surrounding Grid) with a Border and the Background binding as in this example (different property as it's not bound to the DataGrid data) and it worked well.

**My problem in short:** Binding a SolidColorBrush to a Border takes no visible effect if inside of a DataGrid - the same code works if outside. Anyone can help please?

Thank you for your help in advance!

Ben

(edited because the code block ate a line)

Comment: Just as a sidenote, you usually should not handle things like Colors in the ViewModel (if it's not a property of your model). If the color just represents a status like Error/OK it's a better idea to express this via a property (bool, enum, etc..) and apply a style trigger to that properties.

Comment: You are right. Thank you for the input. I tried it that way before, but as it didn't work I tried it via the Brush - which didn't work as well. But I should rewrite my code as soon as it's doing what I want it to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for trying to help. **I found the issue and it was me.** The names I'd like to call myself are to explicit to use them here.

If you want to do what I did you can use my original code. It works as expected. If you want to know which issue i fought - I created a new ViewModel property to be bound to the DataGrid but I forgot to change the ItemsSource binding.

Mea culpa, mea maxima culpa...

Answer (score 1):

Set the binding with the same method used to set your item source

```
{Binding Path=DataContext.SourceColumnBackground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}
```

Also, make sure you are binding to System.Windows.Media.Brush

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I don't want to change the Background of the ComboBox, I want to change the Background property of the Border. The ComboBox uses the RelativeSource attribute because its source is only found once.

The type of the bound property is System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush (and it works in a different context, the problem only occurs inside the DataGrid).

Comment: Where does the SourceColumnBackground property come from? Is it a single property within your data context or is it a property which is contained within your data grid's item source?  If it is a single property within your data context you will need to use the relative source (I'm no expert, but it has something to do with the visual/logical tree of the data grid, as your already binding to the data grids item source anything contained within the data grid will use whatever your item source is binded to as its data context)

Comment: The property comes from the same enumeration item as the text property for the Label so no need for RelativeSource (in my understanding).